# ¿ Puedo publicar mis propias experiencias aquí?

Tags: discusión, temática

Últimamente no paso apenas por el sitio principal; el trabajo me ocupa mucho tiempo.

En éste, debido a su naturaleza, me encuentro practicamente a diario con *imprevistos*, *curiosidades*, y *funcionalidades no previstas*.

Creo que muchas de estas cosas podrían ser de utilidad a otros; algunas me han ocupado más tiempo del previsto, otras se han resuelto de forma *curiosa*, y las menos están aún pendientes. Por supuesto, casi ninguna está documentada **en español**.

Estoy barajando la posibilidad de crear un *blog*; siento que es una pena *perder* tanto esfuerzo y tiempo invertidos.

Ahora bien: todo se ajusta **exactamente** al formato de SOes: hay un problema breve, concreto, y reproducible. Y se aplica una solución (más o menos breve, pero siempre concreta).

La pregunta: ¿ Es correcto publicar estás experiencias aquí ? Sé que se anima a auto-respondernos, pero estamos hablando de **bastantes** preguntas/respuestas. No quiero que se tome como auto-bombo y terminar saturado de negativos :-(

Comment: ¡Claro! [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](/help/self-answer). Yo lo he hecho bastantes veces (en SO) y da gusto ver que algunas de las preguntas con el tiempo van ganando atención y hay gente que comenta agradeciendo que dieras el paso. Así que te animo a darlo :)

Comment: Tal vez, dado que ya sabes la solucion, podrias poner la pregunta y darle un par de dias para que tratemos de llegar a la misma solucion. sobre todo para las cosas curiosas o no previstas.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿ No sería eso *desconsiderado* por mi parte ? ¿ Proponer un problema, que algunos intentarán resolver, cuando ya conozco **una** solución ?

Comment: @Trauma desconsiderado, depende del planteamiento. Si creas la pregunta, creas la respuesta y propones que quien quiera se anime a dar alternativas. Igual otros puntos de vista lo solucionan de otra forma, otras veces puede que la solución que planteas sea la correcta. Y siempre puedes añadir un link a esta pregunta en un comentario para que se entienda la intención. El resultado sería una pregunta con soluciones alternativas. Creo que es válido y útil.

Comment: @OscarR Así como propones, si me parece correcto. Publicar la pregunta con su respuesta, pidiendo opiniones al respecto. ¿ Quizás con una etiqueta al efecto ? `revisión-de-código` no me parece adecuada. ¿ Tal vez `soluciones alternativas` ?

Comment: @Trauma En el modelo de SE todas las buenas preguntas están abiertas a soluciones alternativas aún y cuando haya una respuesta aceptada, de hecho la respuesta aceptada puede ser cambiada en cualquier momento. Una forma de **solicitar enfáticamente** respuestas alternativas es ofreciendo una recompensa.

Comment: @Rubén Tienes razón, lo que dije es totalmente redundante :-)

Answer (score 4):

> ¿ Es correcto publicar estás experiencias aquí ?

Lo veo bastante viable, es una forma de compartir el conocimiento y esfuerzo con otros y a la vez tener documentado en un formato de calidad (formato SO) nuestras experiencias, esto nos puede ser útil a futuro para resolver problemas similares, además de que otro usuario publique una forma más eficiente de resolverlo.

La recomendación sería ver que no exista una pregunta relacionada en SOes y hacer la publicación acorde a la guía [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/). Cómo efectivamente lo indicas "todo se ajusta exactamente al formato de SOes: hay un problema breve, concreto, y reproducible. Y se aplica una solución (más o menos breve, pero siempre concreta)."

No veo necesario incluir una nueva etiqueta para estas preguntas/respuestas con las que existen es suficiente.

> Sé que se anima a [auto-respondernos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), pero estamos hablando de bastantes preguntas/respuestas. No quiero que se tome como auto-bombo y terminar saturado de negativos :-(

Al contrario, el hacer la publicación requiere invertir tiempo y hacer un esfuerzo adicional y la reputación que puedas ganar es bien merecida.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿ Es correcto publicar estás experiencias aquí ? Sé que se anima a auto-respondernos, pero estamos hablando de bastantes preguntas/respuestas. No quiero que se tome como auto-bombo y terminar saturado de negativos :-(

La votación se **debería** realizar con base en el contenido de la publicación **nunca** con base en quién es el autor de la misma y por ello el número de preguntas realizadas por el autor no debería influir.

Lo peor que debería pasar es que el sistema te bloqueara el realizar nuevas publicaciones temporalmente por publicar demasiado en un lapso breve de tiempo, pero esto sólo te debería preocupar si piensas publicar todas esas bastantes preguntas el mismo día o mes. Los detalles sobre los límites de preguntas están en [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/289691)

Cabe destacar que las preguntas auto-respondidas pueden resultar difíciles pues el autor debe de hacer el ejercicio de recordar o imaginar lo buscado/investigado antes de encontrar la solución  pues las preguntas en un hilo auto-respondido debería cumplir con todo lo que se espera de una buena pregunta.

Si nos vamos al lado de los puntos de reputación recuerda que los votos negativos le descuenta 2 al autor, los votos positivos en las preguntas suman 5 y en las respuestas suman 10, así que no hay que tenerle tanto miedo a los negativos, además hasta podrías ganar la medalla [presión-de-pares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) (luego de eliminar una publicación con -3 ) :)